# YouTube embed URL validation regex in Laravel 8 in controller

Tags: php, regex, laravel

I want to validate my youtube URL like this https://www.youtube.com/embed/xxxxxxxx. How to use the regex in variable link for this?

my code is like this in controller

```
$validatedData = $request->validate([
    'title' => 'required',
    'subtitle' => 'required|unique:news',
    'category' => 'required',
    'link' => 'required|regex:??',
    'image1' => 'required|image',
    'image2' => 'image',
    'image3' => 'image',
    'image4' => 'image',
    'content' => 'required'
]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add some custom validation logic for achieving this .Hope this code snippet can help you-

```
'link' => [
        'required',
        'url',
        function ($attribute, $requesturl, $failed) {
            if (!preg_match('/(youtube.com|youtu.be)\/(embed)?(\?v=)?(\S+)?/', $requesturl)) {
                $failed(trans("general.not_youtube_url", ["name" => trans("general.url")]));
            }
        },
    ]
```

Or like below-

```
public function passes($attribute, $requesturl)
{
    return (bool) preg_match('/^.*(youtu.be\/|v\/|u\/\w\/|embed\/|watch\?v=|\&v=|\?v=)([^#\&\?]*).*/',$requesturl);
}

'link' => new RuleYoutube,
```

Comment: One step further would be to define a custom rule like described in the docs: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#custom-validation-rules - so the code is clearer and the rule easier to reuse.

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this, we need to use array for regex validation in laravel.

```
// ^(?:https?:\/\/)? : Optional protocol
// (?:m\.|www\.)? : Optional subdomain
// (?:youtu\.be\/|youtube\.com\/ : Mandatory domain name with .be or .com TLD
// (?:embed\/|v\/|watch\?v=|watch\?.+&v=))((\w|-){11})(?:\S+)?$ : Mandatory query string
// /i : Case insensitive match

$request->validate($request, [
   'link' => ['required', 'regex:/^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:m\.|www\.)?(?:youtu\.be\/|youtube\.com\/(?:embed\/|v\/|watch\?v=|watch\?.+&v=))((\w|-){11})(?:\S+)?$/i']
]);
```

Comment: This snippet is missing its educational explanation.  Please explain how your pattern works and describe it with the assumption that future readers are not as skilful as you are.